Hiding all UI elements within a blender window with the python API
I am trying to create a Blender window that has no UI elements, only the 3D Viewport. Specifically, I want to remove the top bar. Is it possible to do this using the Python API?


To access this functionality, right-click the Editor Type button in the upper-left corner of the 3D Viewport area. In the context menu that appears, choose Header > Show Header. Alternatively, you can create and register a custom Operator to toggle this setting for you.

Simply paste this in the Text Editor and run the script then press F3 in the 3D Viewport and search for "Toggle Region Header".
import bpy

class ToggleRegionHeaderOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.toggle_region_header"
    bl_label = "Toggle Region Header"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        space = context.area.spaces.active
        space.show_region_header = not space.show_region_header
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ToggleRegionHeaderOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ToggleRegionHeaderOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

